# Label Encoder unseen label

Tags: encode, label-encoding

I am trying to encode a users input but I keep getting this error:

"Value Error: y contains previously unseen labels: 'xxx'"

I think it is because the label is in X instead of Y when I split it. I am not sure on how i can transform it using X instead of Y.

appreciate any help given for this.